# Laravel foreach save data

Tags: laravel, for-loop

I have a loop for create or update data like below

```
        foreach ($goods_list as $goods) {

            $w_estim_mp = WEstimMp::where('event_seq', \LoginInfo::event_data()['event_seq'])
            ->where('goods_seq', $goods['goods_seq'])
            ->first();

            if (!isset($goods['note'])) {
                $goods['note'] = '';
            }

            if (!isset($w_estim_mp)) {
                $w_estim_mp = new WEstimMp;
                $w_estim_mp->event_seq = \LoginInfo::event_data();
                $w_estim_mp->goods_seq = $goods['goods_seq'];
                $w_estim_mp->mp_item_category = $mp_item_category;
            } 

            $w_estim_mp->num = $goods['num'];
            $w_estim_mp->note = $goods['note'];
            $w_estim_mp->proc_flg = 2;
            $now = (new \Carbon\Carbon())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $w_estim_mp->update_dtime = $now;
            $w_estim_mp->save();
        }
```

I don't know why i can update only last value of $goods_list.
Help me T.T Thank you!

Comment: What's the error that you are getting?

Comment: use `dd($goods_list) ` and show the output

Comment: @AmolRokade: i didn't get any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my question!
I don't know why but i work, finnaly, after i changed to

```
        foreach ($goods_list as $goods) {
            $goods_seq = $goods['goods_seq'];
            $num = $goods['num'];

            $w_estim = WEstimMp::where('event_seq', $event_seq)
            ->where('goods_seq', $goods_seq)
            ->first();

            if (!isset($goods['note'])) {
                $goods['note'] = '';
            }
            $now = (new \Carbon\Carbon())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            if (!isset($w_estim)) {
                $w_estim = new WEstimMp;
                $w_estim->event_seq = $event_seq;
                $w_estim->goods_seq = $goods_seq;
                $w_estim->mp_item_category = $mp_item_category;
                $w_estim->num = $num;
                $w_estim->note = $goods['note'];
                $w_estim->proc_flg = 2;
                $w_estim->update_dtime = $now;
                $w_estim->save();
            } else {
                $w_estim = WEstimMp::where('event_seq', $event_seq)
                ->where('goods_seq', $goods_seq)
                // ->first()
                ->update([
                    'num' => $num,
                    'note' => $goods['note'],
                    'proc_flg' => 2,
                    'update_dtime' => $now,
                ]);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_pop to remove the last element and array_push to insert a new element. Follow an example:

```
<?php

 $initial_array = [1,2,3];

function change_last($array, $value) {
    $removed_element = array_pop($array);
    array_push($array, $value);
    return $array;    
}

$changed_array = change_last($initial_array, 4);
print_r($changed_array);
?>
```

and here a live example:
https://tech.io/snippet-widget/ZfEzgjj

Comment: I dont understand what you mean! I don't want to change the array